# List is null even with HTML.HiddenFor

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am getting `null exception` whenever I try to post my form. The list in model not retaining values even though I have the `@HTML.HiddenFor` in the View.

What am I donig wrong?

**My Controller:**

[image]

**My view:**

[image]

**On post:**

[image]

Comment: in post method are you repopulating countries ?

Comment: No. I thought that that's not needed after this HiddenFor in view. Am I misunderstanding it ?

Comment: on post you need to repopulate

Comment: Normally you need to populate your model in Controller and Pass it to the view. What you are doing is posting the model to Controller, I assume the Controller is getting correct values from the user? Can you please clarify why are you displaying the same View once the model is posted to controller?

Comment: its a mapping creation page, user fills out all the mapping clicks `Create` and gets on the same page. May be I should just redirect to the initial view that will take care of populating the list again

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the hidden inputs have the following names or else the model binding won't work and Model.Countries will be null:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Countries[0].id" value="something" />
<input type="hidden" name="Countries[0].country_name" value="something" />
<input type="hidden" name="Countries[1].id" value="something" />
<input type="hidden" name="Countries[1].country_name" value="something" />
...
```

Or you could repopulate your model in the Post action before the view is returned instead of using hidden inputs:

```
model.Countries = db.mstr_country.ToList();
return View(model);
```